# Redirect - 4 total parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

**@anubhava** and **@RavinderSingh13** have continued to help me learn and progress to where I am today with this script. This is what I have so far:

````
##1st rule with one parameter: $id--
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ /directory/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

##Parameters are $id and $class
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?id=(\d+)&class=(\w+-class)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(\w+-class)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&class=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

##Rule with two parameters: $id and $name--
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?id=(\d+)&name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L,QSA]```
````

Now, I would like to add one more rule with only **one** parameter instead of two. However, this parameter uses PHP **$_GET['name']** in the url. I am trying to add one more rule that rewrites **http://IPADDRESS.com/file.php?name=JohnDoe** to **http://IPADDRESS.com/newdirectory/JOHNDOE**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following. Please make sure to clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ /directory/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

##Parameters are $id and $class
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?id=(\d+)&class=(\w+-class)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(\w+-class)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&class=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

##Rule with two parameters: $id and $name--
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?id=(\d+)&name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /directory/file.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

##Rule with two parameters: $name--
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/file\.php\?name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /directory/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]*)/?$ /directory/file.php?name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Question though, since the original **file.php** is not in another directory, should the last line be adapted as follows?
`RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]*)/?$ file.php?name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: @ccc, yes please try it once(that will assume that your htaccess and file.php are in same folder) and let me know, I will change it then.